# is it better idea to upgrade to new versions of a Web app created in java or migrate to Ruby on Rails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been searching for pros and cons of both technology but still not sure what to do

We have a web application created in java but its tool [sic] old and we have to [sic] options either to revamp it completely in java or write fresh code in ruby on rails

-from developers point of view both are new language [sic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look into JRuby.  It's a Ruby interpreter written in Java.  The upside to this is that you can switch between Ruby and Java in the same project effortlessly, and you have access to the Java standard libraries and its whole ecosystem of third-party libraries.  The main disadvantage to JRuby is you can't use any Ruby gems with compiled components (you can use Rails though).

Ruby vs Java:

1. Ruby is more modern and more flexible: it supports many different programming paradigms, whereas Java is strictly OOP.
2. Ruby has a terser syntax and often requires much, much less effort to get the same tasks done as they would require in Java.
3. Java has a larger standard library and broader support for legacy technologies.
4. Ruby is often slower to run and requires more memory than Java, though this gap has closed somewhat with the release of Ruby 1.9.
5. There is a broader base of support for Java (though Ruby's support base is by no means small).

Ruby on Rails vs J2EE:

1. Rails requires less time and effort to get a website up and running.
2. Rails requires less configuration, provided you are willing to accept Rails's sensible defaults.
3. Like Ruby, Rails requires much, much less code to accomplish the same task as it would require in J2EE.
4. J2EE libraries (such as Hibernate) are often more flexible and more powerful than their counterpart Rails libraries (e.g., Active Record), but at the expense of coding and maintenance overhead.